# X,Y,D,E collinear in simple incircle configuration with a right triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> There is a right triangle $ABC$ with right angle at $A$. Let the incircle touch $AB$ and $AC$ at $D$ and $E$, respectively. $X$ and $Y$ are the arc midpoints of minor arc $AB$ and $AC$ on $(ABC)$. Show that $X,Y,D,E$ collinear.

The lemma above is a step in in proving a different result which won't be provided here. I am sure there will be an easy proof to the above, but I appear to be having difficulty in showing that it is true. Sorry for the lack of information about what I have already tried, but indeed I have not made too much progress; thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In any triangle (not necessarily right-angled), $XY$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AI}$, as the circles centred at $X$, $Y$ passing through $I$ also go through $A$ (this is the famous incentre-excentre lemma).

When $\angle A=90^{\circ}$, then $ADIE$ is a square, so $DE$ is also the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AI}$.